# SQLServer 2008 to find the sum of all rows and sum of components of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

/* I have a problem with querying in SQLServer 2008 to find the sum of all rows and sum of portions of rows. I used ROW_NUMBER (), outer_apply, but I can not solve the problem. I search a few days on your web site stack_overflow but I can not find anything similar.
Now I have no idea even how to do it.
Can anyone help me???

Input data: Section Number, Initial Node, Final Node, Area, Section is the distance among two nodes. To each node belongs to a particular area. */

```
A       B       C      D        
--------------------------------
Section Initial Final  Area     
Number  Node    Node                  
================================
1       0       1      0    
2       1       2      5    
3       2       3      3.1  
4       3       4      3.7  
5       4       5      2.7  
6       5       6      0    
7       6       7      4.1  
8       7       8      0    
9       8       9      2.8  
10      9       10     4.6  
11      10      11     3.2
12      11      12     3    
13      12      13     5    
14      13      14     3.5  
15      1       15     3    
16      15      16     5.6  
17      16      17     4.7  
18      17      18     2.8   
19      6       19     0    
20      19      20     3.8  
21      20      21     5    
22      19      22     2.9  
23      8       23     4.4
```

/*  Need to calculate a cumulative area (Area Cum) which belongs to every node down the network.
Result should be*/

```
A       B       C     D        E        F
-----------------------------------------------------
Section Initial Final  Area     Area     Description
Number  Node    Node            Cum               
=====================================================
1       0       1       0       72.9    =SUM(D1:D23)
2       1       2       5       56.8    =SUM(D2:D14)+SUM(D19:D23)
3       2       3       3.1     51.8    =SUM(D3:D14)+SUM(D19:D23)
4       3       4       3.7     48.7    =SUM(D4:D14)+SUM(D19:D23)
5       4       5       2.7     45      =SUM(D5:D14)+SUM(D19:D23)
6       5       6       0       42.3    =SUM(D6:D14)+SUM(D19:D23)
7       6       7       4.1     30.6    =SUM(D7:D14)+D23
8       7       8       0       26.5    =SUM(D8:D14)+D23
9       8       9       2.8     22.1    =SUM(D9:D14)
10      9       10      4.6     19.3    =SUM(D10:D14)
11      10      11      3.2     14.7    =SUM(D11:D14)
12      11      12      3       11.5    =SUM(D12:D14)
13      12      13      5       8.5     =SUM(D13:D14)
14      13      14      3.5     3.5     =SUM(D14)
15      1       15      3       16.1    =SUM(D15:D18)
16      15      16      5.6     13.1    =SUM(D16:D18)
17      16      17      4.7     7.5     =SUM(D17:D18)
18      17      18      2.8     2.8     =SUM(D18)
19      6       19      0       11.7    =SUM(D19:D22)
20      19      20      3.8     8.8     =SUM(D20:D21)
21      20      21      5       5       =SUM(D21)
22      19      22      2.9     2.9     =SUM(D22)
23      8       23      4.4     4.4     =SUM(D23)
```

Comment: Can you provide a further description of why each sum is what it is, for example in row 1, you have `=SUM(D1:D23)`, and row 2 has `=SUM(D2:D14)+SUM(D19:D23)`, what is in row 2 that is not in row 1 that means `D15:D18` should be excluded, or what is in `D15:D18` that means it should not be included in the total in row 2? If you can't explain your logic in words it is almost impossible for anyone else to do it with SQL.

Comment: I'm with @GarethD here - I see some logic here, but I can't completely get it

Comment: Mr.GarethD and Mr.Roman Pekar thanks for your attention and your time

Comment: It is about branched water supply network . At each Nod belongs particular area (Area), which should be satisfied with water. Throughout each node top –down( 1-23) need to pass water to satisfy the water needs of the surfaces. At this stage it is necessary to determine how much surface area belongs to each Nod cumulative (AreaCum) bottom-up.

Comment: The problem is that in some places downwards there are nodes dividers (Area = 0), as is the case in NOD 1(0-1), where the network is divided into two routes, 1-14 and 1-18. This means that the surface of the route of 1-18 does not belong to 1-14 route, because the surface of the 1-18 route is above the surface of route 1-14.

Comment: As an example: the NOD 1 belong surfaces of all nodes downwards and therefore the cumulative area (AreaCum) is 72.9 (ha), while node 2 surfaces belong to fewer nodes that have cumulative area of 56.8 (ha), it is less 16.1 (ha) as belonging to the cumulative route  1-18 (SectionNumber 15 , InitialNode 1 ,FinalNode 15 = 16.1 ha).

The same happens in NOD 6

Answer (score 1):

Using [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), you can do something like this:

```
WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, NULL S  FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.*, COALESCE(r.S,r.SectionNumber) S FROM Table1 t
    INNER JOIN RCTE r ON r.FinalNode = t.InitialNode  
)
, CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT S, SUM(Area) AS AreaCum FROM RCTE 
    GROUP BY S
)
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(c.AreaCum, t.Area) AreaCum FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN CTE2 c ON t.SectionNumber = c.S
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac9e4/1)**